Two answers coming to this limit problem, $0$ or $-1?$

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2}\right)$$
exists and equal to $L$ then find $[L]$ where $[.]$ where denotes the greatest integer function.

I first unwrapped the summation. As you can see, all the terms but two will get cancel. We will be left with $\ln(0.5)$ at the end and so it means that $L$ should be $0$. Or the answer should be $0$.
But this is not the answer given.

Given solution
\begin{aligned}  
 L=& \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(\left(\frac{1+\frac{(k-1)^{2}}{n^{2}}}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{2}}\right)\right)\\  
 L=& \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1-1 / n} \ln \left(1+x^{2}\right)-\int_{0}^{1} \ln \left(1+x^{2}\right) d x\right)   
 \end{aligned}
Since the first integral denotes an area which will be very slightly less than the area denoted by second integral as the limits of integration of the first integral are very slightly less than that of the second one, so $L$ must be very slightly less than $0$.
Hence $[L]$ must be equal to $-1$.

My question is, is this even valid$?$ I have never seen this kind of approach in any of the questions I've solved so far in limits. Can we actually do this$?$

Is my answer $(0)$ correct or their's $-1?$ And if their answer is right, then can we evaluate the limit precisely$?$
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I don't see how they get $-1.$ $$\int_{1-1/n}^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}<\frac{1}n\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^2}=\frac{n}{n^2+(n-1)^2}\to 0.$$

@ThomasAndrews they gave the argument that the area covered by the first curve will be slightly less than the second one

The given answer may be calculating $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\lfloor\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2}\right)\right\rfloor$$. But of course $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is not everywhere continuous.

@peterwhy yeah it can be tha case

In the given solution, the limit from the numerators should be
$$\lim {n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum{k=1}^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{(k-1)^{2}}{n^{2}}\right) = \int_{0}^{1} \ln \left(1+x^{2}\right) d x$$
which is a left Riemann sum and equal to the integral from the denominators.

"Slightly less" isn't an argument and isn't  enough - the "slightly less" goes to $0.$

Oh, somehow I missed that they want $\lfloor L\rfloor.$ If it was $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$$ their argument might be true. But that is not the question, as you've given it to us. Your approach would give $-1$ this way, too, since $\frac1n\log\frac12$ is negative and goes to zero. But that is not the question you've asked. You've asked $$\left\lfloor\lim_n \cdots\right\rfloor$$

@ThomasAndrews i understand that..thnx

In any even, the two sums, after you break up the log of the fraction, both converge to the same value - one is the left Riemann sum of $\log(1+x^2)$ and the other is the right Riemann sum. They both converge to the same integral, so the difference in the limit is $0.$ You can say one is $\int_0^{1-1/n}$ in the limit, because in the limit, there is no $n.$ You can, howeverr get that the left Riemann sym minus the right Riemann sum is always negative, since $\log(1+x^2)$ is increasing on $(0,1),$ and goes to zero.

Are you certain they were asking for $\lfloor \lim stuff \rfloor$ and not $\lim \lfloor stuff \rfloor$.  It's pretty intuitive that $\lim stuff =0$ but $stuff < 0$ so $\lfloor stuff \rfloor = -1$ and $\lim \lfloor stuff \rfloor=\lim -1 = -1$.   But $\lfloor \lim stuff \rfloor =\lfloor 0 \rfloor = 0$.

I must iterate that "Since the first integral denotes an area which will be very slightly less than the area denoted by second integral as the limits of integration of the first integral are very slightly less than that of the second one, so L must be very slightly less than 0." is garbage!  That $a_n < b_n$ does NOT implie $\lim a_n \le \lim b_n$ is one of the most fundamental concepts such an argument is not at all acceptable.  $\frac 1n > 0$ but $\lim \frac 1n = 0$ and *!NOT! $\lim \frac 1n > 0$ should be one of the first limits anyone ever learns.

@fleablood hmm...you're right...even I thought that it's not a good argument

Let $$f(x) = \log (1+x^2).$$  Then for all $n \ge 1$ and $k \ge 1$,
$$\log \frac{n^2 + (k-1)^2}{n^2 + k^2} = \log \frac{1 + \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^2}{1 + \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2} = f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).$$
So $$\sum_{k=1}^n \log \frac{n^2 + (k-1)^2}{n^2 + k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = f(0) - f(1) = - \log 2,$$
hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log \frac{n^2 + (k-1)^2}{n^2 + k^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-\log 2}{n} = 0.$$

This is what I've done too....so I guess that the answer given is wrong and ours is correct??? Thanks

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad The given solution is not rigorous because the limit of integration should not be a function of $n$ when evaluating the Riemann sum.  Moreover, the use of integrals is completely unnecessary, as you observed that the sum is telescoping.  Finally, what the question actually means to evaluate depends on whether the floor function is inside the limit, or outside the limit, as peterwhy commented.

For once, go from the sum to the product
$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{(k-1)^2+n^2}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\times \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+4}\times \frac{n^2+4}{n^2+9}\times \cdots$$ Therefore
$P_n=\frac 12$ and the problem ends with
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2}\right)=-\frac {\log(2)} n$$

As an alternative to the fine solution given by heropup, we have
$$0\le -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log \frac{n^2 + (k-1)^2}{n^2 + k^2} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(1+\frac{2k-1}{n^2 + (k-1)^2}\right)$$
$$\le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left(1+\frac{2k}{n^2 }\right)\le \frac{2}{n^3} \sum_{k=1}^n k =\frac{n(n+1)}{n^3} \to 0$$
